# Enable haptic Feedback on react-native touchable view

Tags: react-native, haptic-feedback

I an writing a react-native app, And I noticed that while the buttons look like native buttons when clicked - they do not behave as one (At lease not like android button behave).

Clicking on android app button - make a sound and give the user an haptic Feedback. 
On the sound I saw that there is github discussions and open issue, but I could not found anywhere anything about the haptic Feedback.

How can I make my view (any touchable view..) to make haptic feedback on click? 
This is really important feeling in an app.

I want something like this (In android)

```
View view = findViewById(...)
view.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.VIRTUAL_KEY);
```

This doesn't require from the app to have permission for `Vibrate`.

And managing haptic feedback on my own with the `Vibrate` api will cause users that disable this option globally to experience bad behavior

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Expo with react-native, I recommend you to use [Expo haptics](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/haptics/)

After installing the library  You can use it like:

```html
<TouchableOpacity onPress = { ()=> { 
     Haptics.notificationAsync(Haptics.NotificationFeedbackType.Success)
     or
     Haptics.impactAsync(Haptics.ImpactFeedbackStyle.Light) 
     or
     Haptics.selectionAsync()
   
 } } > </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: where to put this code and is it similar to 3d touch?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in Vibration module [facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback#onpressin)

```js
import { Vibration } from 'react-native';
...

<TouchableWithoutFeedback
  onPressIn={() => Vibration.vibrate()}
/>
```

Remember to include this in your AndroidManifest

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Comment: This does not mimc hapticFeedback feeling. I edited my question to be more specific.

Comment: Isn't haptic feedback just vibration on tap? Is you want to change the vibration it takes parameters.

Comment: I know, and the constant for android is Vibration.vibrate(3). But this mean I need to handle it on my own - different for each OS, plus to check what the user android global settings are. I would have thought that this will be a something that react-native platform will take care of.

Comment: The permission thing fixed it for me, thanks Ivan. However it is not working on iOS. Is there some permission to add for iOS?

Comment: This is why I switched to nativescript which provide 100% native feeling

Answer (score 2):

I found this component on github https://github.com/charlesvinette/react-native-haptic

I didn't try it yet, but it should help you to get the haptic feedback you want.

Answer (score 2):

I also have nearly the same requirements and I ended up using this library [react-native-haptic-feedback](https://github.com/milk-and-cookies-io/react-native-haptic-feedback).

Keep in mind that haptic feedback is available only on some latest android devices and in iOS above iPhone 6s. Here is a simple code snippet:

```
import ReactNativeHapticFeedback from "react-native-haptic-feedback";

const options = {
  enableVibrateFallback: true,
  ignoreAndroidSystemSettings: false
};

ReactNativeHapticFeedback.trigger("impactMedium", options);
```

In your case, it will work directly with the button's onPress method such as:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{ReactNativeHapticFeedback.trigger("impactMedium", options);}} />
```

> Note: I found that the most versatile type which is supported by maximum devices is `impactMedium`.

Comment: If anyone having trouble of without getting any haptics from React Native on version > 0.60 on any iOS devices that support haptics feedback, just go to your React Native project directory on the XCode folder structure (on the top-left handside of XCode)  => Go to Build Phases tabs (on the top middle of the XCode screen) => dropdown Link BIrary with Libraries => Add by click on (+ Drag to reorder linked binaries) => search for "libRNReactNativeHapticFeedback.a => add it. Then stop running and re-run your project or https://github.com/junina-de/react-native-haptic-feedback/issues/40

Answer (score 0):

I published a project on Github which provides this functionality. 
Check this repo out: [react-native-haptic-view](https://github.com/hamidhadi/react-native-haptic-view)