# How to get half a millisecond vibration on ios in react native with expo?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, vibration

How to get half a millisecond vibration on ios in react native with expo? Similar to the vibration you get when typing on a keypad of a phone.
I seem to get it on android with this `Vibration.vibrate([0, 0, 0, 30])` but it does not replicate the same on ios

here is the code below

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Vibration.vibrate([0, 0, 0, 30])} style={{ marginTop: 100, alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>Vibrate</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: I *really* don't think you mean .5ms. Maybe 50ms, but based on your inputs, I'd guess 30ms. The term you're looking for is Haptic. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43760502/enable-haptic-feedback-on-react-native-touchable-view

Comment: Expo.Vibration doesnt offer changing vibration rate, use https://github.com/junina-de/react-native-haptic-feedback/

Answer (score 1):

vibration in react-native is platform specific.

```
import { Vibration, Platform } from "react-native";

// vibrate is platform specific. default is 400ms
  const vibrate = () => {
    if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
      // this logic works in android too. you could omit the else statement
      const interval = setInterval(() => Vibration.vibrate(), 1000);
      // it will vibrate for 5 seconds
      setTimeout(() => clearInterval(interval), 5000);
    } else {
    
      Vibration.vibrate(5000);
    }
  };
```

Then use it as callback:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={vibrate} style={{ marginTop: 100, alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>Vibrate</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: I tried this for iOS. The vibration is not continous in this case. Is there a way to make it continous without stopping in the middle?

Answer (score 0):

`react-native-haptic-feedback` makes the thing on iOS
as mentioned by Medet Tleukabiluly here's the link: https://github.com/junina-de/react-native-haptic-feedback/ but unfortunately it didn't work on Android for me.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me :

Vibrates for 100ms

Sleeps/No vibration for 50ms

Vibrates for 100ms

Sleeps/No vibration for 100ms

Vibration.vibrate([100, 50, 100, 100]);